# Why was comment deleted by a moderator when it is not offensive or otherwise invalid?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Please read the post. This excerpt I gave recently in comments:

> I get it as I see "too chatty" and other reasons far to often and flag them as such. A fair critique is a fair crtitique. And I do have a particular gripe against users who submit nothing but "opinions" as an excuse for an answer on a regular basis. Such as is the case here, and I believe it is only fair to users of the site that this is pointed out. That was basically my point of the post

I recently commented on both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32563613/5031275) and a submitted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32564137/5031275).  The question was not a good question and was closed, but an answer appeared before the question was closed.  The answer did answer the question, but it is really more of an opinion.  However my effort to help in debunking content that should not have been posted has been ignored.

Now I did also go to lengths to explain the reasoning for the hold votes (as I prefer to call them) to the OP.  Before the question was closed, that opinion-answer appeared. I downvoted it for being an opinion instead of a definitive answer, and I left a descriptive comment on the answer provided.

That comment was intended to warn people that the answer really wasn't an answer and should not have been posted as one. Yet someone chose to remove that comment, perhaps because it included the text "meaningless dribble."  I'm unhappy with useful criticism in my comment being removed from that poor answer.  Likewise, I'm unhappy with the user in question needing to be educated on the low quality of answers and general opinion based responses that seem consistent.

If I am wrong in thinking that my comment should not have been deleted then let it be so.  But I cannot see how this helps anyone seeking help here when all they get in response is someones opinion, and that as a community we allow people to do this on a regular basis.

Comment: What is with the "scare quotes"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please? Big difference between someone trying to emphasize  than "newbie scare quotes". Not exactly peppered with is it? Just use of punctuation.

Comment: No, this is absolutely peppered with useless scare quotes.

Comment: *"Not exactly peppered with is it?"* - only one paragraph doesn't have any!

Comment: I count 19 uses of the quotes, which feels like peppering to me... Then note that they aren't typically used for emphasis - try bold or italics instead...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for not reading the content. You helped.

Comment: I have also read the content, but it didn't really help - what are you actually asking?

Comment: Make the content easier to read, and people are more likely to read it and respond to that instead of the ways in which it's hard to read...

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay if you really want to help make this better then the main point is ( quoting not scaring ) *"I made a valid critical comment that was not offensive in any way, it was removed. Why?"*. Being the most succicnt way I can put this. That is if anyone is interested in helping at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not so sure that adding bold/italics would be an improvement... Replacing one ill conceived method of emphasis with another seems to be missing the larger point that the post doesn't make sense to begin with.

Comment: @BLakesSeven AFAIK, if there is a certain number of flags on a comment, it gets auto-deleted (don't have the specifics on how much of which flag you need, but I know that there is an automatic deletion). With that in mind, if a certain number of users flagged your comment, the moderation was automated by the system. (and if your main point is what you just quoted, why can't we see it verbatim in your post? I'd say it would help understanding the point of this post)

Comment: If that's your question, then you may get a response from the moderator that actioned the flag. But, long story short, don't expect comments to stick around, especially if you throw around terms like *"meaningless dribble"* (did you mean "drivel"?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then honestly what is the point of providing any useful information at all? If it's just up to the judgement of someone who cannot tell the difference betwen useful or otherwise then why bother to contribute anything? I'd prefer to feel more valued for contibution than so easily discounted as what is happening right here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe [Meaningless dribble?](https://youtu.be/sIV8uL0pI_M)

Comment: @apaul34208 Yes. Meaninless dribble is exactly the point. How does this "help" anyone?

Comment: @BlakesSeven if someone writes a bad answer, downvote it. For comments, see [the guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). That's it. Attitude is a big part of contributing here, so try to [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) while you're at it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Agreed. No problem with that. Why is my critique so offensive that it "needs" to be removed? There is nothing but hard facts in the content given. This is is over moderation that I am talking about.

Comment: @BlakesSeven given that *the comment has been removed*, how can we tell you that? All we know is that you wrote *"meaningless dribble"* in it, which is neither constructive nor accurate use of English, so you shouldn't be surprised it was removed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So if you remove "facts" from peoples consideration, then you remove the context for them to make their own judgement. If I had made "personal remarks" against the poster or otherwise "defamed" them in any way then it would be understandable and I would accept that I did wrong. The incorrect answer deserves the critisim that it attracts.

Comment: @BlakesSeven then please feel free to add another comment outlining your **constructive criticism** of the answer. Try not to describe things as *"meaningless dribble"*. Please note that if you put in facts in quotes, as "facts", it generally means *"not facts"*, so in this case your quoting is actively counter-productive.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Sorry, bad joke. You'll probably get a better response if your question is a little more concise. As in "_Why was this specific helpful comment removed?_" with the exact text of the removed comment and why you added it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If that is really the point of judgement here then that is a sad state of affairs. The balance of content is a fair critique. Are you going to remove another fair critique that does not contain such a phrase? Which phrases need to be avoided to achive the end goal of highlighting the bad response from the author and to the end reader? Clearly something needs to be done. So what to do?

Comment: @BlakesSeven we can't say anything about *"the balance of content"*, because **we still don't know what it was**. *"Are you going to remove another fair critique that does not contain such a phrase?"* - I am not a moderator, and wouldn't flag a comment that was genuinely constructive, if that's what you mean. *"Clearly something needs to be done"* - won't somebody *please* think of the children!

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you cannot do anything then why are you responding/wasting my time.

Comment: @BlakesSeven why are you wasting ours?  We're just trying to help, but you haven't given us enough information.

Comment: @BlakesSeven ...because you asked a question on Meta, where I am one of the participants. If you're not planning to do anything with the feedback (*that you've asked for*) other than argue with it, why are you wasting everyone else's?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Though I seriously do hate myself that more information has probably been said in comments, then what more information do you need. Tell me and I will hapilly give.

Comment: Well without the "offending" comment, this question is not really answerable. Hopefully a (diamond) moderator will post it somewhere.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Do you remember what the comment actually said?

Comment: @user000001 I think the point I am making is there "was no offending comment" yet someone deemed "PG" to be "X" rated.

Comment: @apaul34208 In sunbtext it basically said "The answer is essintially just links and opinions, and was not required of a question that was not complete in itself'. The "meaningless dribble" content was also in there, but notably also made on the main question and in context not offensive in any way, yet the whole point is the comment seems to be judged as such when it did otherwise make a fair critique of a really bad response.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I get it, that's why the word is in quotes. Keep in mind though that comments are deleted for other reasons too, such as "too chatty, "not constructive", "obsolete", etc. Only a moderator can tell you (and us) what really happened.

Comment: @user000001 I get it as I see "too chatty" and other reasons far to often and flag them as such. A fair critique is a fair crtitique. And I do have a particular gripe against users who submit nothing but "opinions" as an excuse for an answer on a regular basis. Such as is the case here, and I believe it is only fair to users of the site that this is pointed out. That was basically my point of the post.

Answer (score 24):

Well, [Neil](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn), seeing as how this is like the third or fourth account you've created since your last was suspended for rudeness, I'd think you would have gotten the message by now. Stop being rude and abusive to people in your comments. This isn't the only comment of yours we've had to delete in recent weeks.

For the sake of discussion, this was the comment you left on someone's answer:

> See how I mention "meaningless dribble" above? This is exactly what an opinionated answer is. This would do better as a blog post I think. The "links" are again just "opinions" and there is no content of value here, which is mostly a product of the question not being "definitive" in itself. SO content needs to be "answers" and this does not meet such criteria in any way.

That reads to me as both insulting to the asker and answerer, so it was rightly deleted when flagged by the community.

Frankly, you're lucky we've let you keep this account for as long as we have.

Comment: Ah the all important missing context... I just love it when people come to meta with this sort of thing and intentionally leave out the back story.

Comment: For serveral times now I have had to repsond "Not Neil". My ex partner who used to live with me but you still persist.So you are basically incorrect.

Comment: @BlakesSeven If you're not Neil you have an eerily similar use of quotes in your writing. Quirks like this are often a dead giveaway of authorship.

Comment: @apaul34208: Or maybe he just influenced his partner. Wonder why they split...

Comment: @apaul34208 So you never lived with anyone and picked up similar habbits? All sounds a little to paranoid to me. And understand I had this kind of repsonse before. Beleive me that I made an effort here before and had the same accussation made. And by the same person.

Comment: @BoltClock She. thankyou very much. Now is the content above opininated on being more offensive that your comment or which? Let's all play nice as I hope we all really want the same goals please.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Fair enough, I acknowledge this is possible, but if you're wondering why people assume that you're the same person, keep in mind that you're posting from the same IP with a very similar writing style.

Comment: @apaul34208 I still live in the same house as I did before. How simple is that? Tired of this and in a way my ex is right. I just want to help as I can. If it cannot be accepted then please move along as you must.